# RGeo::Geos.supported? true in irb but false with bundler in macOS mojave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, bundler, geos, rgeo

In macOS mojave `gem install rgeo` installs and in irb `RGeo::Geos.supported?` returns `true`

Now after doing `bundle install` and going to rails console via `bundle exec rails c`, it returns false.

How to resolve this issue with bundler and rgeo geos support?

Comment: This is a similar, you should have a look
https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/issues/26#issuecomment-6024997

Comment: I guess not. In that linked issue, it not working for him even in irb. Mine working fine in irb but not with bundler. `bundle exec rails c` and there its false which is true in irb.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue, did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and I solved it by deleting my bootsnap cache, so if you're also using bootsnap this might work:

```
rm -rf tmp/cache/bootsnap-*
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, it worked for me! I was commenting out the `require 'bootsnap/setup'` line in `config/boot.rb` but didn't want to do this every time. Is there any chance you could elaborate on why your solution fixes this?